# Extremely high latencies on Hazelcast distributed map get operations

Tags: hazelcast

We use a distributed Hazelcast map in our project, and have recently run into a problem with extremely high get latencies. We used `IMap.get(...)` calls, which in some cases took hours to complete. After this incident, we switched to `IMap.getAsync(...)` API with timeouts, which resolves the problem for us, but I am curious if anybody had a similar issue.

Our Hazelcast version is 3.9.0. During the incident we had `hazelcast.operation.call.timeout.millis` set to 5000, and `async-backup-count="3"` with `read-backup-data="true"`. We also had sporadic CPU usage spikes (up to 100% for several minutes) on some hosts due to unrelated background processing, which could potentially affect Hazelcast.

The only suspicious thing that we found in the logs was that around the incident all hosts were complaing about one particular host, like this:

```
Oct 24, 2018 3:53:01 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandler
WARNING: [hostX]:5702 [dev] [3.9] No Invocation found for call timeout response with callId739863 sent from [hostY]:5702
Oct 24, 2018 3:53:01 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandler
WARNING: [hostX]:5702 [dev] [3.9] No Invocation found for call timeout response with callId739864 sent from [hostY]:5702
Oct 24, 2018 3:53:01 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandler
WARNING: [hostX]:5702 [dev] [3.9] No Invocation found for call timeout response with callId739852 sent from [hostY]:5702
Oct 24, 2018 3:53:01 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandler
WARNING: [hostX]:5702 [dev] [3.9] No Invocation found for call timeout response with callId739870 sent from [hostY]:5702
Oct 24, 2018 3:53:01 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandler
WARNING: [hostX]:5702 [dev] [3.9] No Invocation found for call timeout response with callId739874 sent from [hostY]:5702
Oct 24, 2018 3:53:01 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandler
```

In the `hostY`'s logs:

```
Oct 24, 2018 3:53:01 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor
WARNING: [hostY]:5702 [dev] [3.9] MonitorInvocationsTask delayed 14294 ms
Oct 24, 2018 3:53:01 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor
WARNING: [hostY]:5702 [dev] [3.9] BroadcastOperationControlTask delayed 13544 ms
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to share the Hazelcast cluster member logs when you are having the high latencies and CPU spikes?

Comment: We didn't have detailed Hazelcast diagnostics logging at that time. I've updated the question with suspicious logs that we did notice.

Answer (score 3):

From the `hostY`'s logs, it seems `hostY` suffering from GC pauses. `MonitorInvocationsTask` is scheduled to run every seconds but it says its execution is delayed for 14 seconds. And `BroadcastOperationControlTask` should be scheduled nearly every second due to your config (`hazelcast.operation.call.timeout.millis / 4 = 1250 ms`) but similarly it's delayed for 13 seconds.

You can verify this by enabling GC logs. Additionally Hazelcast should print `HealthMonitor` logs periodically when memory and/or CPU usage exceeds some threshold.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. We did have `HealthMonitor` logs on all hosts around the incident, they were printed out approximately every 30 seconds.

Comment: We found a similar reported problem with add/remove calls - https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/11470. Can this be related, or is it something completely different?

Comment: [IMap.add/remove- EntryListener randomly hangs](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/11470) looks like a client issue and was fixed in 3.9.1. But according to your logs, members in cluster are suffering from pauses. If you look at the health monitor logs, you should see memory usages and minor/major GC pauses there.